# Разные шаблоны для WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать в WooCommerce на странице категорий и в товаре разные шаблоны ? Мне нужно, чтобы на странице категорий был сайдбар, а в товаре его не было... Как это сделать ? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от темы, которая выводит sidebar. Вариантов реализации может быть очень много. В стандартной теме twentyseventeen можно отключить вывод динамического сайдбара через фильтр:

```
function is_active_sidebar_filter( $is_active_sidebar, $index ) {
    if ( ( 'sidebar-1' === $index ) && is_product() ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $is_active_sidebar;
}
add_filter( 'is_active_sidebar', 'is_active_sidebar_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Код рабочий, проверил на тестовом сайте.